# In a Content Pane mouse movements are logged and shown

Tags: java, constructor

I was trying to learn to develop plug-ins in Eclipse and after following the tutorial provided with Eclipse, tried to expand the code by writing a short Java class to track and display mouse movements on a text area. I got the code for that too from an Oracle Java document. Following is the java class from where I call the mouse tracking class (`MouseEventDemo`):

```
package com.example.helloworld.handlers;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;

/**
 * Our sample handler extends AbstractHandler, an IHandler base class.
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler
 */
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public SampleHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * the command has been executed, so extract the needed information
     * from the application context.
     */
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MouseEventDemo md = new MouseEventDemo();
        md.callStart();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Next, in the `MouseEventDemo` class, `callStart()` initiates GUI painting by calling `createAndShowGUI()` which in-turn calls `MouseEventDemo` class constructor and completes the job.

```
package com.example.helloworld.handlers;

import javax.swing.*;


import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class MouseEventDemo extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    BlankArea blankArea;
    JTextArea textArea;
    static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String  wString;
    public void callStart(){
         try {
             UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
         } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
         /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
         UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
         createAndShowGUI();
         //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
         //creating and showing this application's GUI.
         //creating threaded implementation
         /*javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 createAndShowGUI();
             }
         });*/
    }

    public MouseEventDemo(String xx){
        super(new GridLayout(0,1));
        wString = xx;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "assigned");
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new MouseEventDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MouseEventDemo(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, wString);
        blankArea = new BlankArea(Color.YELLOW);
        add(blankArea);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 75));
        add(scrollPane);

        //Register for mouse events on blankArea and the panel.
        blankArea.addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));    
    }


    void eventOutput(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {
        textArea.append(eventDescription + " detected on "
                + e.getComponent().getClass().getName()
                + "." + NEWLINE);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());      
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        eventOutput("Mouse pressed (# of clicks: "
                + e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        eventOutput("Mouse released (# of clicks: "
                + e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        eventOutput("Mouse entered", e);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        eventOutput("Mouse exited", e);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        eventOutput("Mouse clicked (# of clicks: "
                + e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
    }
}
```

In all this, there are two object instances of `MouseEventDemo` getting created. First when `callStart()` is called from `SampleHandler` and then again in `MouseEventDemo` class within `createAndShowGUI` method. The first one is not used after the initial call at all and seems a complete waste and an inefficient use of resources (just to call one public method in `MouseEventDemo`).

Is there some better way of accomplishing the intended tasks?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to divide `Handler` and `Panel`. For example, `MouseEventDemoPanel` will contain GUI construction and `MouseEventDemoHandler` will contain your `mousePressed()`, `mouseMoved()`, etc. And use the observer pattern.
2. Try to move the `callStart()` method to the `SampleHandler` class. This allows you to call `new MouseEventDemo()` once.